# Modify the domain name for media items in XM Cloud

Tags: nextjs, xm-cloud, mediaurls

On our XM Cloud site built using Nextjs the URL for media items is structured as follows: `https://edge.sitecorecloud.io/prod/media/project/videos/video1` and it currently works correctly. However, my goal is to serve the media assets from the site URL like `https://xyz.com/prod/media/project/videos/video1`.

I attempted URL rewriting to achieve this, but when I tested the modified URL `https://xyz.com/prod/media/project/images/image1` it resulted in a 404 error.

Note: we've managed to accomplish the configuration for images using Next/Image through the following code:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
```

Any suggestions on how to approach the media URL configuration to meet my requirement and serve the media assets from the site domain?

Comment: What values do you have you set for the "Target hostname" and "Hostname" fields in "sitecore/content/<site collection>/<site>/Settings/Site Grouping/<site>"?